# How to set up webhooks with the Mailchimp module

Tags: hooks, emails

I just installed the newest version of the MC module into my D7 instance and was wondering how I can enable webhooks for the lists that I have within the lists tab.

I have already set up a test list on the MC side and created an API key and I see the list populating on the Drupal side so I have that working just fine.

When I go to enable the webhooks feature on my list on the D7 side I get this msg:

**You can change this setting back from the mailchimp administrative UI.** I then click on enable hooks. Its working to do something but then get hit with: **Unable to perform webhook action "enable" for list my-test-list**.

I also see that I need to enter a callback URL on the MC side but I'm confused as to what link I need to use there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with my site, which is fixed now. It seems like the error message pops only if you are on HTTPS secure protocol. If you are on HTTPS try disabling it and try enabling your mailchimp lists. After you enable the mailchimp list now you can re-enable the HTTPS.

There is a [bug on 7.x.3.1](https://www.drupal.org/node/2276143) version Make sure you are using the latest version 7.x.3.2

On secure pages settings you can ignore these pages loading from HTTPS.

**example.com/admin/config/system/securepages**

`admin/config/services/mailchimp
admin/config/services/mailchimp/*`